# How can i get process original file name for a process?

Tags: c++, windows, process

say, i've a binary called vlc.exe, if i rename it to abc.exe, it still runs fine. But if you see properties of abc.exe, you can see an attribute "Original FileName" and its value is vlc.exe. So, is there an api to get this "Original FileName"?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [Version Information Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468915%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) on MSDN.

You'll need to `GetFileVersionInfo` to get the version info data, then `VerQueryValue` for the `OriginalFilename` entry.